# Responsive website: How to get the new value from jQuery when orientation changes?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have a responsive image that changes it's size (width and height) according to horizontal and vertical orientation. I want to set the position of an element based on the height of the image. When I grab the height of the image through jQuery `$(".div-inner img").height()`, it returns the height of the image. Now when I change the orientation, the height's value remains the same although the actual image changes in size. Looks like I cannot get the new height without page refresh. Is there a way to get the new height through jQuery without refreshing the page?

Comment: It would help if you provided a bit of info about why the image changes size when you change orientation. Are you sure the actual image changes size, or does the browser just zoom in a bit? Or are you doing something to change the size of the image manually or via a media query in CSS?

Comment: Are you capturing the `resize event`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have a few options.

**1)** Capture the window.onresize event

```
window.onresize = function (event) { 
var height = $(".div-inner img").height();
//Do your thing
}
```

The downside of using this is that ANY resize is called. So this will probably fire a million (not literally) times on a typical browser resize. So you need to combine with a timout so it only can fire every few seconds.

So really it would be something like this.

```
var resizeTimeout;
    window.onresize = function (event) {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
       resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                      // Alert when browser resized
                      alert ('Resized');
                     // DO YOUR THING
       }, 1000);
};
```

**2)** Use orientation change (switching from Portrait to Landscape in mobiles and back again). Downside is it won't do anything thing in a desktop / laptop browser that is resized because no orientation is changed..

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    // Alert the orientation value
    alert(window.orientation);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I am using an image slider with this. With the `orientationchange` event, it seems to work well but after I click on the next button in my slider and then change orientation, it fails. But if I just load the page and change orientation without clicking on the sliders, it seems to work perfectly. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: What slider are you using? Sliders tend to apply fixed and inline styles to elements of a slideshow which can affect what you're trying to do. I tend to you jQuery cycle because it's really lightweight and easy to use. It's most basic usage is simply `$('.slidercontainer').cycle();`
What you can do is destroy the slideshow and rebuilt it on orientation change. So for jQuery cycle in the orient change event you would start it with `$('.slidercontainer').cycle('destroy');` then `$('.slidercontainer').cycle();` Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I am using carousel slider in Bootstrap. I think it doesn't have `destroy` functionality - I'm not sure. I resolved it another way. I noticed the value of `var height` is changed to 0 when orientation is changed after moving to the next slide. I detected the image height in jQuery and if it is equal to 0, I set the position of the element to a specific value. Although it doesn't seem like a perfect solution, this worked.